# How to seed roles and capabilities in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, docker-compose, mongoose-schema

I am new to working on a MongoDB and Docker, I am working on an application and couldn't find a more subtle way to seed my database using an npm run command. First I created a file called seed.js and then associated it to npm run seed command on the package.json file.

On the seed.js file I import Mongoose and the models but two things I will need to do is:

- Create roles, if they don’t exist yet
- Create capabilities, if they don’t exist yet and associate it to the
  roles

The Roles that i want to create are:

- admin (description: Administrator)
- viewer (description: Viewer)

Capabilities

I need to check each endpoint of the Users service that should require authentication and create an adequate capability. Example: updateUser updates the user data. This could be done by the own user (so there must be an updateUserOwn capability) and by an administrator (that will have an updateUsers capability). I will have to analyse each endpoint and judge what is adequate but I cannot still find a way around getting the initial role and capabilities to the database.

**UPDATE:**
On the seeding itself, the updated solution works, but it requires lot of code and repetition that could probably be fixed by loops. I’d like to start creating the roles first which means creating an array with objects, with the data from the roles to be created. Each role has the fields role and description

```js
const userRole = [{
role: admin
description: Administrator
},
{
role: viewer
description: Viewer
}]
```

The idea is that if the role exist it doesn't need to update but I don't know how do I loop through the array and create a role only if it doesn’t exist. Something like using updateOne, with the upsert: true option, but with the data on $setOnInsert as this will add the data only if a document is inserted.

I only need create and not update because in the future I’ll edit roles directly through the API. So, if a change was made on the admin role, for example, the seed will not overwrite it

During the loop, I'll need to create an associative array called rolesIds that will store the ObjectId of the created roles. It should result in something like this:

```js
[
  "admin": "iaufh984whrfj203jref",
  "viewer": "r9i23jfeow9iefd0ew0",
]
```

Also each capability must have an array of roles it must be associated to. Example:

```js
{
  capability: "updateUsers",
  description: "Update the data of all users",
  roles: ["admin"]
}
```

How do I loop through the array on each element, prepare it to be inserted using the array with object IDs. Instead of roles: ["admin"]? something like roles: ["iaufh984whrfj203jref"], otherwise there’ll be a cast error. Remember each capability may be associated to more than one role, so I'll probably need to loop through them but I cannot find a way to create that logic.

Users Model

```js
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    .......
    role: {
      ref: "roles",
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    },
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

Role Model:

```js
const roles = new mongoose.Schema({
  role: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  capabilities: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "capabilities",
    },
  ],
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("roles", roles);
```

Capabilities Model:

```js
const capabilities = new mongoose.Schema({
  capability: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("capabilities", capabilities);
```

**UPDATED:** seed file:

```js
const seedDB = async () => {
  if (!process.env.DB_URI) {
    throw new Error("Error connecting to MongoDB: DB_URI is not defined.");
  }

  try {
    await mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_URI, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      useCreateIndex: true,
    });
    console.log("Connected to MongoDB");
    const tasks = [
      Capability.findOneAndUpdate(
        { name: "updateUserOwn" },
        { capability: "updateUser" },
        { upsert: true }
      ).exec(),
      Capability.findOneAndUpdate(
        { name: "updateUsers" },
        { capability: "updateUser" },
        { upsert: true }
      ).exec(),
      // Seed more...
    ];

    const [updateUserOwn, updateUsers] = await Promise.all(tasks);
    Role.bulkWrite([
      {
        updateOne: {
          filter: { role: "Admin" },
          update: { capabilities: [updateUsers] },
          upsert: true,
        },
      },
      {
        updateOne: {
          filter: { role: "Viewer" },
          update: { capabilities: [updateUserOwn] },
          upsert: true,
        },
      },
    ]);
    console.log("seeded data", tasks);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`Error connecting to MongoDB: ${error}`);
  }
};

seedDB();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right path overall.

Because capabilities are used as a reference you'd have to fetch or create them (get a ref) before assigning them to a role.

#### This could be your seed logic:

```js
const tasks = [
  Capability.findOneAndUpdate(
    { name: 'updateUserOwn' }, // matches or creates this capability
    { capability: 'updateUser' }, // adds this to the object
    { upsert: true, new: true } // `new` guarantees an object is always returned
  }).exec(),
  Capability.findOneAndUpdate(
    { name: 'updateUsers' },
    { capability: 'updateUser' },
    { upsert: true, new: true }
  }).exec(),
  // Seed more...
];

const [
  updateUserOwn,
  updateUsers,
] = await Promise.all(tasks);

// We can use bulk write for the second transaction so it runs in one go
await Role.bulkWrite([
  { 
     updateOne: {
       filter: { role: 'Admin' },
       update: { capabilities: [updateUsers] },
       upsert: true,
     }
  },
  { 
     updateOne: {
       filter: { role: 'Viewer' },
       update: { capabilities: [updateUserOwn] },
       upsert: true,
     }
  }
]);
```

We seed capabilities one by one using [findOneAndUpdate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) so we can get a reference to each capability we intend to use on the roles

Then we use [bulkWrite](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.bulkWrite) to seed the roles

*I might have swapped the capabilities and their names but I hope you get the general idea*

---

The seed would have been simpler if there weren't references involved - you could just use `bulkWrite` everything in one go, but in order to create object with inner references or add references to such object you first need to have the actual reference

Comment: Thank you so much @kidroca, that was a great solution you stated and really helpful. Yes I won't be listening for any requests it should connect and close. I updated the question, I hope you understand where I am stuck at now? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can create static mapping and loop through which would reduce the code a bit, and make things easier. This would also allow you to skip seeding items that already exist

Since capabilities are reused through roles I want to create them first, but it's no problem to alter the logic to first create roles and then capabilities, though it might not be as straight forward

> Also each capability must have an array of roles it must be associated to.

This is called a "many to many" relationship (as roles also have an array of references to capabilities) which would only complicate logic. Are you sure you really need it - mongoose/monogo won't manage it automatically for you:

- when you add a capability to a role you'd also need to sync and add the role inside capability.roles - manually
- and the reverse - adding a role inside capability.roles you'd need to sync this and also manually add the capability to role.capabilities
- the same thing for deleting capabilities or roles - manual cleanup
- it can fail and would need to recover - e.g. a capability is added to role.capabilities but for some reason execution stopped and the role was not added to capability.roles - so the whole handling might need to be wrapped in a transaction
- there are ways to cross reference roles and capabilities without have to have a "many to many" relationship

#### Here's a simple approach using `save` middleware to sync many to many relationships for create/update

Role.js

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const roles = new mongoose.Schema({
  role: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  description: String,
  capabilities: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'capabilities',
    },
  ],
});

roles.pre('save', async function save() {
  // Doesn't need to run if there are no capabilities
  if (!this.capabilities || this.capabilities.length === 0) return;

  const Capability = mongoose.model('capabilities');
  await Capability.updateMany(
    { _id: {$in: this.capabilities} },
    // Adds only if it's missing
    { $addToSet: { roles: this._id }},
  );
});

// Todo: similar logic to remove from capabilities if role is deleted

module.exports = mongoose.model("roles", roles);
```

Capability.js

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const capabilities = new mongoose.Schema({
  capability: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
  },
  roles: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'roles',
    }
  ]
});

capabilities.pre('save', async function save() {
  if (!this.roles || this.roles.length === 0) return;

  const Role = mongoose.model('roles');
  await Role.updateMany(
    {_id: {$in: this.roles}},
    {$addToSet: {capabilities: this._id}},
  );
})

// Todo: similar logic to remove from roles if capability is deleted

module.exports = mongoose.model("capabilities", capabilities);
```

Here's an update seed routine:

Seed.js

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Capability = require('./models/Capability');
const Role = require('./models/Role');

const CAPABILITIES = {
  UPDATE_USERS: {
    capability: 'updateUsers',
    description: 'Update the data of all users',
  },
  VIEW_USERS: {
    capability: 'viewUsers',
    description: 'View public data of users',
  },
  UPDATE_OWN_RECORD: {
    capability: 'updateUserOwn',
    description: 'Update user own data',
  }
}

const ROLES_TO_SEED = [
  {
    role: 'admin',
    description: 'Administrator',
    capabilities: [CAPABILITIES.UPDATE_USERS, CAPABILITIES.VIEW_USERS],
  },
  {
    role: 'viewer',
    description: 'Viewer',
    capabilities: [CAPABILITIES.VIEW_USERS, CAPABILITIES.UPDATE_OWN_RECORD],
  }
]

const seedDB = async () => {
  await connectToDb();
  await seedRoles();
};

const connectToDb = async () => {
  if (!process.env.DB_URI) throw new Error('DB_URI is not defined.');

  console.info('Connecting to database...');
  await mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_URI, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
  });

  console.info('Connected \n');
}

const seedRoles = async () => {
  console.log('Seeding Roles...');
  // runs sequentially to skip creating duplicate capabilities
  for (const role of ROLES_TO_SEED) {
    await findOrCreateRole(role);
  }

  console.log('Complete \n');
}

const findOrCreateRole = async ({capabilities, role, ...defaults}) => {
  console.info('Looking for role: ', role);
  const fromDb = await Role.findOne({role}).exec();

  if (fromDb) {
    console.info('Role already exists skipping... \n');
    return fromDb;
  }

  console.info('Role does not exist - creating new \n');
  const doc = new Role({role, ...defaults});

  // All capabilities (per role) can be created/found in parallel
  const roleCapabilities = await Promise.all(capabilities.map(findOrCreateCapability));
  doc.capabilities = roleCapabilities.map(c => c._id);

  await doc.save();
  console.info('Role created: ', role);
  console.info('');
  return doc;
}

const findOrCreateCapability = async ({capability, ...defaults}) => {
  console.info('Looking for capability: ', capability);
  let doc = await Capability.findOne({capability}).exec();
  if (doc) {
    console.info(`Capability ${capability} found - using existing...`);
  }
  else {
    console.info(`Capability ${capability} does not exist - creating new`);
    doc = new Capability({capability, ...defaults});
    await doc.save();
  }

  return doc;
}

seedDB()
  .then(() => {
    console.info('Exiting...: ');
    process.exit(0);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Seed failed');
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  })
```

We have a dictionary of capabilities and a list of roles that we can map to db operations.
The idea is that each role should contain the full definition of a capability, it can be used to either find the existing capability or create it if it doesn't exist

For each role in the list we make a query to see if it exists.

- When it exists we do nothing and move to the next role
- When it doesn't exist we have all the data needed to create it and create/find any capabilities that it might need

When you figure out all the roles and capabilities of the application you just put them in the ROLES_TO_SEED and CAPABILITIES static mappings

The script relies on the above mentioned middleware modifications in models

---

#### And a small bonus

You don't need many to many relationship to match capabilities to the roles they are used in. Here's how you can aggregate that information if only the Role model have an array of capabilities (refs). Run this after the database is seeded:

```js
const showCapabilitiesUsages = async () => {
  const result = await Capability.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'roles',
        let: {searched: '$_id'},
        pipeline: [
          {
            $match: {
              $expr: {
                $in: ['$$searched', '$capabilities']
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        as: 'roles'
      }
    }, {
      $project: {
        _id: 0,
        capability: 1,
        description: 1,
        usedInRoles: {
          $map: {
            input: '$roles',
            as: 'role',
            in: '$$role.role',
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]).exec();

  console.log('Aggregate result: ', result);
}
```

You should get a result like:

```sh
Aggregate result:  [
  {
    capability: 'updateUsers',
    description: 'Update the data of all users',
    usedInRoles: [ 'admin' ]
  },
  {
    capability: 'viewUsers',
    description: 'View public data of users',
    usedInRoles: [ 'admin', 'viewer' ]
  },
  {
    capability: 'updateUserOwn',
    description: 'Update user own data',
    usedInRoles: [ 'viewer' ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, it should would work:

```js
const roles = [
  {
    name: 'admin',
    description: 'Administrator',
  },
  {
    name: 'viewer',
    description: 'Viewer',
  },
];

const capabilities = [
// Capabilities
  {
    name: 'createCapability',
    description: 'Create a new capability',
    roles: ['admin'],
  },
  {
    name: 'deleteCapability',
    description: 'Delete a capability',
    roles: ['admin'],
  }

  // Roles
  {
    name: 'createRole',
    description: 'Create a new role',
    roles: ['admin'],
  },
  {
    name: 'deleteRole',
    description: 'Delete a role',
    roles: ['admin'],
  },


  // Users
  {
    name: 'updateUser',
    description: 'Update current user data',
    roles: ['viewer'],
  },
  {
    name: 'updateUsers',
    description: 'Update the data from any user',
    roles: ['admin'],
  },
];


const seedRoles = async (roles) => {
  if (0 == roles.length || !Array.isArray(roles)) {
    return;
  }

  console.log('');

  for (const role of roles) {
    const savedRole = await Role.findOneAndUpdate(
        {name: role.name},
        {$setOnInsert: role},
        {upsert: true, new: true, rawResult: true},
    );

    if (!savedRole) {
      console.log(`Role “${savedRole.value.name}” already on database.`);
    } else {
      console.log(`Role “${savedRole.value.name}” added to database.`);
    }
  }
};

const seedCapabilities = async (capabilities) => {
  if (0 == capabilities.length || !Array.isArray(capabilities)) {
    return;
  }

  console.log('');

  for (const capability of capabilities) {

    const rolesToPush = capability.roles;
    delete capability.roles;

    const addedCapability = await Capability.findOneAndUpdate(
        {name: capability.name},
        {$setOnInsert: capability},
        {upsert: true, new: true, rawResult: true},
    );

    if (!addedCapability) {
      console.log(
          `Capability “${addedCapability.value.name}” ` +
        `already on database.`,
      );
    } else {
      console.log(
          `Capability “${addedCapability.value.name}” ` +
          `added to database.`,
      );

      if (rolesToPush && Array.isArray(rolesToPush)) {
        rolesToPush.forEach(async (role) => {
          const roleToPush = await Role.findOne({name: role});

          if (roleToPush) {
            roleToPush.capabilities.push(addedCapability.value);
            await roleToPush.save();
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }
};

const seedDb = async (roles, capabilities, users) => {
  try {
    await seedRoles(roles);
    await seedCapabilities(capabilities);
    console.log('roles', roles);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};

module.exports = seedDb;
```